# Why does $(x-2)^2\geq 1$ imply that $|x-2|\geq\sqrt1$ or $|x-2|\leq -\sqrt1$?

Tags: inequality

I want to improve my theoretical background to make it rock solid.

Given

$(x - 2)^2 \geq 1$

O learnt that taking the square root of boot sides yields

$| x -2| \geq \sqrt{1}$ or $| x - 2 | \leq - \sqrt{1}$

Here, I have two questions:

1. Why does taking the square root transforms it from $(something)^2$ to $|something|$? Why the "module" symbols?

   I believe this is redundant, not really necessary. Am I right?

and

2. Why does the sign change direction?

   I know this is because $x$ can be $ \le 0$, so I need to go into a little bit more depth about the theory on swapping signs. As far as I can tell we only swap inequality sign when dividing or multiplying by a negative number

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: $y^2\ge1\implies y\ge1 $ or $y\le-1$;  $|x-2|\ge0\gt-1$ so $|x-2|\le-1$ doesn't make sense

Comment: perhaps you're confusing with $y^2\ge1\iff|y|\ge1$

Comment: When you wrote $p$ did you mean $x$?

Comment: Yes - sorry. I meant "x" not "p". But your other 2 comments didn't help much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The key lies in understanding the square root *function,* which by definition should give a unique value. Unfortunately, there are always two candidates satisfying the equation $x^2=y,$ where $y> 0$ is given. Mathematicians have convened to choose the positive root satisfying this equation as *the* result of the square root *operation.* Thus taking the square root of a nonnegative quantity, say $x^2,$ always gives a nonnegative result. This operation is often symbolised by $\sqrt{},$ so that we always have $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|,$$ by *definition.* Thus, $\sqrt 4 = 2,$ and *not* $-2.$ Hence, whenever you take the square root of an expression of the form $E(x,y,z,\ldots)^2,$ you must have the result to be $|E(x,y,z,\ldots)|.$
2. The sign does not change direction. If you have an inequality of the form $$x^2\ge y,$$ where $y\ge 0,$ then you may take the square root of both sides (and the inequality is respected since the square-root function is monotonic), to get $$|x|\ge \sqrt y,$$ and the right hand side is uniquely defined by (1), so there's no negative value at all. Thus, applying this to your inequality, namely $$(x-2)^2\ge 1,$$ we obtain $$|x-2|\ge 1.$$ But if you want to solve this inequality, you don't need to take square roots at all. Just transpose and factor, to get $$(x-2)^2-1\ge 0,$$ which gives $(x-2-1)(x-2+1)=(x-3)(x-1)\ge 0,$ and so on.

Comment: Great - Fully understood about the module. Didn't quite understand why you get $( x -2 -1)(x -2 +1)$ tho. I just don't know where the $+1$ came from.  Nonetheless (x-3)(x-1) is another way to resolve the initial equation, so it makes sense.

Comment: @Batmaths A difference of two squares $a^2-b^2$ can always be factored as $(a-b)(a+b).$ That was what I applied.

Comment: True that! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The chain of equivalent transformations should progress first to
$$
|x-2|\ge\sqrt1=1
$$
and then to
$$
x-2\le -1\text{ or }x-2\ge 1.
$$

---

If $|u|\ge a$, then

- either $u\ge 0$ and $u=|u|\ge a$.
- or $u<0$ and $-u=|u|\ge a\iff u\le -a$.

---

You can go from $u^2\ge a^2$, $a>0$, to $|u|\ge a$ because the square function is strictly monotonically increasing on the positive half-axis. Or just simply because in $$0\le u^2-a^2=(|u|-a)(|u|+a)$$ you can divide out the positive second factor.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value of a positive number $n$ is $n.$
The absolute value of a negative number $n$ is $-n,$ which is a positive number.
(For example, $\lvert -2\rvert = -(-2) = 2.$)
The absolute value of zero is zero.

No matter what you start out with, you end up with a non-negative number
(that is, zero or positive).
You might have to use a negative sign ($-n$ instead of $n$) in order to get a result that isn't negative.
(If you start with zero, the negative sign doesn't matter, since $-0=0.$)

So $\lvert x-2\rvert,$ the absolute value of the number $x-2,$ is either
$x - 2$ or $-(x-2),$ whichever one of those is non-negative.

From $(p - 2)^2 \geq 1$ you can conclude that
$\lvert x-2\rvert \geq \sqrt1 = 1,$ full stop.
That is one of the other properties of the absolute value.
There is no case where $\lvert x-2\rvert \leq -\sqrt1 = -1,$
because that would say that there is some number whose absolute value is negative, which cannot happen.

From the fact that $\lvert x-2\rvert \geq 1,$ since you know that $\lvert x-2\rvert$
is actually either $x-2$ or $-(x-2),$ you know that one of the following two statements is true:

$$ x-2 \geq 1 \quad\text{or}\quad -(x-2) \geq 1. $$

If you like, you can rewrite $-(x-2) \geq 1$ as $x-2 \leq -1$;
reversing the signs on both sides of an inequality also reverses the direction of the inequality. Or you could write $-x + 2 \geq 1$ and proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

$|x-2|\le-\sqrt1$ is redundant, since absolute values are never negative.

As for why the module, look at the graph of $x^2$. What values of $x$ give $x^2>1$, for example?

As for how you get a sign change, notice that $|x|>1$ means $x>1$ or $-x>1$, but the latter becomes $x<-1$ when you multiply both sides by $-1$, resulting in a sign change..

Comment: I would say $|x-2|\le-1$ is impossible, not that it's redundant

Comment: *shrugs* I would say "$x$ or false" has a redundant "or false" part. But really the wording is mostly to match the OP.

Comment: I see what you mean now;  "or $|x-2|\le-1$" is redundant

Comment: Ok - Got it. Good to also clarify this point. Thanks